# Typescript 2 Jasmine types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, jasmine, typescript2.0

I'm using Typescript 2 and unless I put a `/// <reference path="..." />` at the top of my spec files, I get an error that `Cannot find name 'describe'`

Here is my spec file:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts" />

import { DashboardSlotComponent } from './dashboard-slot.component';
import { DashboardSlot } from './dashboard-slot.model';

describe('Given a dashboard slot component', () => {
    let sut: DashboardSlotComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        sut = new DashboardSlotComponent();
    });
...
```

package.json

```
"typescript": "2.0.2",
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": [
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "types": [
      "angular",
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "selenium-webdriver",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the Typescript 2 extension.

[image]

Comment: Where do you see the error? When building? If so, what's your build process?

Comment: the build runs fine with no errors, using webpack.. it's just visual studio that can't seem to recognize jasmine.. also when I put the reference at the top of one file, now all of my spec files are able to find jasmine types.. very odd behaviour

Answer (score 0):

With Typescript 2, try:

```
/// <reference types="jasmine" />
```

and make sure you npm install @types/jasmine